# Convergence of eigenvalues in the bulk of the GbetaE?

Tags: pr.probability

Let $\lambda_{k(n)}$, $k(n) / n \to a \in (0,1)$, be an eigenvalue in the bulk
of the $n \times n$ Gaussian Unitary Ensemble (GUE) normalized so that its spectral measure converges to the semi-circle law on $[-2,2]$. It has been shown by [Gustavsson (2005)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2124079) that, for some suitable
centerings $\gamma_{k(n)}$ (the so-called theoretical locations of the eigenvalues),
$$
    \frac { \lambda_{k(n)} - \gamma_{k(n)}}{ \sqrt { \frac {2\ln n}{[4 - \gamma_{k(n)}^2]n^2}}}
$$
converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable.
Is there a similar result for the bulk eigenvalues of the $\textrm {G}\beta \textrm{E}$ ensembles
of [Dimitriu and Edelman (2002)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1936554)?

Comment: At least an answer should be useful.